# Search Algorithm with Incomplete Input

Tags: arrays, string, search

I need an algorithm which will search an array for a string, but the string may not be exactly the same as one of the items in the array.
For example,

```
Array = {"Stack", "Over", "Flow", "Stake"}
input = "Sta"
```

It will need to recognize that Stack and Stake both match the parameters and then choose the one which is first in alphabetical order.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use List, do binarySearch on that list.

```
List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

add elements, while adding elements you can do the following.

```
int x = Collections.binarySearch(arr, key); 
if(x < 0)
    arr.add(-x-1, key);
//for n element this takes n.log_n time.
```

you can do binary search in the list, if the result of binarySearch is > 0, then the key exists in your list, else (-x-1) is the location of the key when it is inserted. go tru each element who begins with input string.

For example, arr is your array and you are searching for input.

```
arr = {"Flow", "Over", "Stack",  "Stake"}
input = "Sta";

int x = Collections.binarySearch(arr, input);
if(x < 0)
    x = -x-1;

if(arr.get(x).subString(0,input.length()).equals(input));
    System.out.println(arr.get(x))
else 
    System.out.println("there is no element starting with input string");
```

Time complexity is O(logn) where n is array's length.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the sorted array, compute the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between each string and your target string, and if it is sufficiently small, return.

What constitutes "sufficiently small" is up to you. You'll probably have to do some testing.

Comment: It looks like OP only cares about finding the first partial match; Levenshtein distance is probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through each element in the array and compare it to the input, determining if the input is contained in the element. Remove any element that does not meet this prerequisite. Finally go through the remaining elements and pick the one that is first alphabetically.

Comment: If you sort the array first, you can just return when you find a first match.

Comment: Also, if the array is sorted, you can do a binary search. It's a little tricky when you're looking for the first of several possible matches, but I have an implementation if there's enough interest.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the index values of the array and find the substring match of the input. Find all the matches and print the one whose index value is the lowest.

For example you will find the substring match for Array[0] and Array[3]. Now you have two matches at 0 and 3. Find the next alphabet of the substirng match. At Arrary[0] the next alphabet to Sta is 'c' but at Array[3] the next alphabet is 'k', here a < k, so the output is Array[0]

Answer (score 0):

You may find [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure useful. It is very efficient to find all words you need.

But memory overhead can be significant if you have many words in the list.